# How to implement ::v-deep on Sass suffixes (&__) selector in Vue2?

Tags: sass, vuejs2, frontend

I am working on scoping all the styles of our Vue2 frontend codebase to prepare for the transition into Vue3. I have read on Vue docs that the `::v-deep` directive enables the child component to receive the scoped styles from their parent components.

We use Sass. Some child component classes don't get the style applied even though I have implemented `::v-deep` on their parent component.

Here's the code of the style section:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .support-category::v-deep {
    .icon-back {
      font-size: 14px;
      color: color(text4);
    }

    .border-bottom {
      border-bottom: 1px solid color(bg3);
    }

    &__subject {
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 700;
    }

    &__accordion {
      font-size: 15px;

      ul,
      ol {
        margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
        margin-left: 14px;
        margin-top: 3px;
      }

      ul {
        list-style-type: disc;
      }

      ol {
        list-style-type: decimal;
      }
    }
  }
</style>
```

Here's the portion of code of the template section:

```
<div v-if="hasSupportCategories">
          <div
            v-for="category in mainSupportCategory.support_categories"
            :key="category.id"
            class="mb-8"
          >
            <v-row>
              <v-col :size="12">
                <v-accordion
                  class="support-category__accordion"
                  :initial-active="mainSupportCategory.support_categories.length === 1"
                >
                  <template v-slot:title>
                    <div class="support-category__subject pb-3 border-bottom">
                      {{ category.title }}
                    </div>
                  </template>
                  <div
                    v-for="item in category.support_items"
                    :key="item.id"
                  >
                    <v-accordion class="support-category__accordion border-bottom py-3">
                      <template v-slot:title>
                        <div class="font-bold">
                          {{ item.title }}
                        </div>
                      </template>
                      <v-markdown
                        :source="item.text"
                        class="pt-3 pb-2"
                      />
                    </v-accordion>
                  </div>
                </v-accordion>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </div>
        </div>
```

The v-accordion component has `::v-deep` implemented as well:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
 .accordion::v-deep {
   .icon-left {
     margin-right: 0.75rem;
     font-size: 12px;
     color: color(text4);
   }
 }
</style>
```

```
<div class="accordion flex flex-col w-full">
        <div
          class="cursor-pointer"
          @click="toggle"
        >
          <slot name="title" />
        </div>
        <div v-show="active">
          <slot />
        </div>
</div>
```

I have tried many techniques but nothing worked out:

```
&::v-deep(__subject) {
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
```

or

```
&::v-deep(&__subject) {
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
```

The only solution that worked is to make this suffixe selector an independent child selector.

```
.subject {
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
```

That works for this case but since we use suffixes a lot in the codebase I would like to find a solid solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

Use a postcss.config.js file and add a 'postcss-prefix-selector' like so to give each class a prefix.

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
    'postcss-prefix-selector': {
      prefix: '#single-spa-application',
    },
  },
};
```